# Why is this javascript expression evaluated to false?

Tags: javascript, null, boolean, boolean-expression

I have written a simple function that nullifies itself after its first call:

```
var nullify = function(){
    nullify = null;
    return 1;     
};
```

If I call it two times, like this:

```
console.log(nullify());
console.log(nullify);
```

Then the 1st expression will return `1`, and the other will evaluate to `null`. All clear up to this point.

If I however do it in a single expression and wrap it in a function:

```
var fun = function(f){
    return f() && !f;
}
```

Then, for some reason:

```
console.log(fun(nullify));
```

evaluates to `false`, while I would expect it to be `true`, since 1st operand will return `1` and the other, as a negation of `null`, `true`.

The evaluation of the right-hand operand occurs when the `nullify` functiion has already called `nullify = null`, is that right? What am I missing?

Comment: Tested it myself, I get `true`.

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake, one sec I edit

Comment: Assignments are done by value, not by reference.

Comment: Tested as well, I get true returned.

Comment: The variable you are using in the nullify function is a local variable not a global variable. So you are actually creating multiple instances of a variable named nullify.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing?

That your `fun` function is testing the variable `f`, which still is bound to the function you passed in, not the variable `nullify` (which has the value `null` indeed).

Comment: So as a result, the nullify function gets nulled, but not f?

Comment: Yes. `f` is not a reference to the `nullify` variable, it is a separate variable holding a reference to the function.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Yes. `f` is just a copy. JS passes by value, not reference.